# Jquery toggle() annoying flickering in Safari

Tags: jquery, toggle

Im having some problems with a simple toggle in Safari. A really annoying flickering at the end of the hide animation. 
Anyone?

CSS

```
#menu {
    position:absolute;
    left: 30px;
    top: 30px;
    padding: 30px;
    background: #FF0;
}

#content {
    width: 400px;
    display: none;
}
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#menu').click(function() {
        $('#content').toggle(700);
    });
});
```

Demos

http://jsfiddle.net/DBeg9/

http://www.clapclap.se/test/toggle.html

Comment: Same problem in Chrome for me. Made a jsfiddle for this: http://jsfiddle.net/DBeg9/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try changing the toggle line to:

```
$('#content').toggle(700,'linear');
```

Comment: I have the same problem with fadeout(), the fix did not work in my case  (7 years later ... so never mind)

Comment: @merlin post a question with your specific code and browser info.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be an issue with setting width/height to 0, which must be what happens at the end of the `toggle` animation just before setting `display: none`.  The only way I figured out how to fix this is by doing the animation the long way:

```
var $c = $('#content'),
    cw, ch;

$c.show();
cw = $c.width();
ch = $c.height();
$c.hide();

$('#menu').toggle(function() {
    $c.css({
        'width': 1,
        'height': 1,
        'opacity': 0
    }).show().animate({
        'width': cw,
        'height': ch,
        'opacity': 1
    }, 700);
}, function() {
    $c.animate({
        'width': 1,
        'height': 1,
        'opacity': 0
    }, 700, function() {
        $c.hide();
    });
});
```

### [See demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cpvMN/)